# Angular - Store Components Instances on services

Tags: angular

I'm currently working on an Angular project that stores in the services the instances of the components created dynamically by the ComponentFactory.

For example, I have a panel that renders a form within a popup (dynamically), and that panel needs to get an output from that form or popup or get/change a value from its attribute. Today, what the panel does is get the instance of that form or popup (stored in the service) and read/change its attribute, it can be of any value, including an Observable.

Is this a good idea?
What would be the best way to work with this?
Maybe a state management like redux?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. My general belief is that, if it is working then you made a fine architecture choice. In this case, it sounds like the form is embedded in the popup panel, so my first impulse is to communicate between the two using `@output()` events and `@input()` properties, possibly in combination with a `@Viewchild` reference. This would eliminate the need for a global service that contains a component instance.

Comment: Hello @JeffryHouser, thanks for your answer!
`@Input` and `@Output` works perfectly, But since popup is a dynamic component, I need your instance because I d'not have access to the html selector.
I did not succeed in getting the instance through the `@Viewchild`. Is it possible?

Comment: If it's a dynamic component that makes use of `ng-content` and content projection, you'd need `ContentChild` instead of `ViewChild`.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Anfilo Please edit your question to share some code, because I don't understand your architecture enough to answer this question.